# Tkinter config() is not updating the label in while loop when msvcrt.getwch() is used

Tags: python, tkinter, while-loop, msvcrt

I'm new in python Tkinter and finding an issue here. I'm trying to get input from the user without pressing enter and want to use the input as updated `label2`. However, I'm getting an updated label only when `while` loop finish executing (only last input is getting displayed). Can you please help me to know where I am going wrong?

```
import tkinter as tk
import msvcrt

root= tk.Tk()
myCanvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 500, height = 200)
myCanvas.pack()

def do_printing():
    count=1
    while (count>0):
        print('Count before= ',count)
        while 1:
            input1 = msvcrt.getwch()
            count=count+1
            break
        label2 = tk.Label(root, font=('Arial', 20))
        label2.config(text=input1)
        myCanvas.create_window(100, 50, window=label2)
        if count==7:
            break
    print('finished')

B1 = tk.Button(root, text ="Option 1", font=('Courier', 12), command= do_printing)
myCanvas.create_window(40, 30, window=B1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: First you have to understand [Event-driven_programming](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming). Read through [`[tkinter] event driven programming`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D+event+driven+programming+entry) and [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29158947/7414759)

Comment: You create new label for each character pressed and put it at the same location, so why do you expect to see all the characters?